# How to run multiple sudo command over ssh using bash script securely and only entering password once

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ssh

I'm trying to write a local Bash script to automatically (set to run by cron) do multiple remote tasks via SSH including some that require sudo.  I want the password to be read from file, then logon via ssh, and then any remote sudo commands. I also want to make sure the password isn't being sent over network by clear text or in the history of the remote computer.

(something like below which doesn't work)

```
#! /bin/bash

sshpass -f mypasswordfile ssh -tt remoteid@remotesever  << EOF
$hostname  # remote server name 
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
whoami
# etc.. etc.. assortment of health, security and other maintenance tasks
EOF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use quotes for this and one -t is enough:

```
#! /bin/bash

ssh -t remoteid@remotesever "\
  sudo -S apt update; \
  sudo -S apt upgrade -y; \
  sudo -S whoami" <<< $(cat mypasswordfile)
```

Comment: I should mentioned some of the tasks I need to do require sed, awk, grep and other utilities that sometimes need single and at times double quotes (why I used heredoc). Is there some tweak to your code that would allow me to use both single and double quotes in some of the commands?

Comment: Just escape double quotes on the commands you will run on the remoteserver and it will works fine, behind whoami try add |sed 's/root/user/g' " <<< $(cat mypasswordfile) and it will works, also doublequotes will work if you try |sed \"s/root/user/g\" " <<< $(cat mypasswordfile), and both mixing double quotes and single quotes try add this behind whoami: |sed \"s/root/user/g\" |sed 's/$/ nr1/g' " <<< $(cat mypasswordfile)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks so much.

Comment: You welcome, don't forget to set this as solved if it works fine. // wuseman

Comment: This kicks up a bunch of errors for me in OS X bash. It says "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal", then asks me to to manually enter passwords for both the ssh connection and the sudo, which means it can't be used in a script since I won't be there to manually type the passwords.

Answer (score 0):

i came up with this using heredoc but @wuseman solution looks much cleaner

```
#!/bin/bash
password=`cat sudopasswordfile`

ssh -t user@host  <<EOF
  echo "$password" | sudo -S whoami
  echo "$password" | sudo df -hT
EOF
```